# Prevent concurrency violation in MySQL and Devart MySQL Connector

Tags: mysql, concurrency, devart

I have inherited support for an application used by a number of charities.

The application uses an Access database for local storage and has a web based interface with a MySQL database.

The application syncs data to the MySQL database using a Devart MySQL connector but this is constantly giving the following error:

```
Concurrency violation: the Update Command affected 0 of the expected 1 records.
```

I've checked and I think this is due to a setting in Devart `Found records` but as I can't recompile the application I don't think there's a way to fix it from that side.

Are there any changes I can make from the database side to prevent these errors?

Answer (score 0):

Setting "FoundRows=true;" in the connection string is the only way to change the provider behavior. Please check your application, maybe it allows modifying the connection string via its *.config file?

Comment: Sadly the connection string is setup using values hard coded into the source concatenated with values from a settings page. Annoyingly I have the source but don't have a license for several of the components.